# XSLT white space in concat

Tags: xslt

I have the following code

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(string($var15_cond_result_exists), string($var16_cond_result_exists))"/>
```

which is concatenating 2 strings. Examle John  and Smith to JohnSmith.

What i want is a space between first name and last name.
I can do this with adding ,' ', between them in concat. Howered there is posibility that there is **no** first name or last name so I don't need the white space.

How can i solve this problem?

Is it possible to use some conditions or there is easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the concat in `normalize-space()` which will trim any excess spaces at the start or end

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="normalize-space(concat(string($var15_cond_result_exists), ' ', string($var16_cond_result_exists)))"/>
```

Note, you may be able to drop the `string` function inside the concat. Try this too

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="normalize-space(concat($var15_cond_result_exists, ' ', $var16_cond_result_exists))"/>
```

Comment: This fixed thank you very much, btw where can i find documentation about this.

Comment: Try the official W3C website for the definitive list: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-space

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which XSLT version you are using. In XSLT 2.0 you can do

```
<xsl:value-of select="$var15_cond_result_exists, $var16_cond_result_exists"/>
```

which will automatically insert a space if and only if both items exist. The conversion to string is automatic in both 1.0 and 2.0.